# iPhone no message alert sound when near MacBook

Tags: iphone, notifications

I've noticed that when my phone is near my MacBook, I only receive notifications for Messages on my MacBook. My iPhone remains silent, and the screen does not light up.

Is this an expected behavior (feature not a bug?), and is there a way to ensure that the phone always dings and lights up for message notifications?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the laptop or is it open during this time?  Messages will only notify you on what it thinks is the active device (in this situation).  If that describes your situation, that's the normal behavior.

Comment: Yea I'm active - looks like this has been addressed in the duplicate tag!